# How to get the filename of ImageView in android?

Tags: java, android, imageview

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain);

    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    Objects.requireNonNull(container).addView(itemView);


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), imageView.getthefilename,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

As you can see in the imageView onClick event, there I want to show the name of the image loaded current in the imageview.

Comment: Where you store the image name? Do you have any array?

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with the answer.

The following code rename will return the filename

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
imageView.getResources().getValue(resourceId, value, true);
String resname = value.string.toString().substring(13, value.string.toString().length());
```